# Find index of object that contain specific string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an array of `NSObject` class. That class contain several properties - name, address, description etc. When user is performing search, I create an array of only "name" properties. Finally, we got table-view populated with "names" (or single cell with correct "name").

Next, I need to display all other properties of that object, for this specific name user found. To be as clear as possible, I want to clarify: I have an array with a lot of objects, that contain many properties. I have value for only one of that properties (don't know which object in array contain that specific name). Now I need to somehow find object in my array, that contain it specific "name". Probably, I need an index of that object, further it would be easy to get all other properties, attached to this `NSObject`.

Im not sure what code I should provide. So, I will paste header of my `NSObject` class:

```
@interface PlaceHolder : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *webPage;
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you!

Update:
NSLog of whole array:

Whole array is (

```
"\U041c\U043e\U0441\U043a\U043e\U0301\U0432\U0441\U043a\U0438\U0439 \U041a\U0440\U0435\U0301\U043c\U043b\U044c \U2014 \U0434\U0440\U0435\U0432\U043d\U0435\U0439\U0448\U0430\U044f \U0447\U0430\U0441\U0442\U044c \U041c\U043e\U0441\U043a\U0432\U044b, \U0433\U043b\U0430\U0432\U043d\U044b\U0439 \U043e\U0431\U0449\U0435\U0441\U0442\U0432\U0435\U043d\U043d\U043e-\U043f\U043e\U043b\U0438\U0442\U0438\U0447\U0435\U0441\U043a\U0438\U0439, \U0434\U0443\U0445\U043e\U0432\U043d\U043e-\U0440\U0435\U043b\U0438\U0433\U0438\U043e\U0437\U043d\U044b\U0439 \U0438 \U0438\U0441\U0442\U043e\U0440\U0438\U043a\U043e-\U0445\U0443\U0434\U043e\U0436\U0435\U0441\U0442\U0432\U0435\U043d\U043d\U044b\U0439 \U043a\U043e\U043c\U043f\U043b\U0435\U043a\U0441 \U0433\U043e\U0440\U043e\U0434\U0430, \U043e\U0444\U0438\U0446\U0438\U0430\U043b\U044c\U043d\U0430\U044f \U0440\U0435\U0437\U0438",
"\U0421\U043f\U0430\U0301\U0441\U0441\U043a\U0430\U044f \U0431\U0430\U0448\U043d\U044f (\U0440\U0430\U043d\U0435\U0435 \U2014 \U0424\U0440\U043e\U043b\U043e\U0301\U0432\U0441\U043a\U0430\U044f \U0431\U0430\U0448\U043d\U044f) \U2014 \U0432\U044b\U0445\U043e\U0434\U044f\U0449\U0430\U044f \U043d\U0430 \U041a\U0440\U0430\U0441\U043d\U0443\U044e \U043f\U043b\U043e\U0449\U0430\U0434\U044c \U043e\U0434\U043d\U0430 \U0438\U0437 20 \U0431\U0430\U0448\U0435\U043d \U041c\U043e\U0441\U043a\U043e\U0432\U0441\U043a\U043e\U0433\U043e \U041a\U0440\U0435\U043c\U043b\U044f. \U0412 \U0431\U0430\U0448\U043d\U0435 \U0440\U0430\U0441\U043f\U043e\U043b\U043e\U0436\U0435\U043d\U044b \U0433\U043b\U0430\U0432\U043d\U044b\U0435 \U0432\U043e\U0440\U043e\U0442\U0430 \U041a\U0440\U0435\U043c\U043b\U044f \U2014 \U0421\U043f\U0430\U0441\U0441\U043a\U0438",
```

and hundred or more similar rows.

Names array is:

```
"\U041c\U043e\U0441\U043a\U043e\U0432\U0441\U043a\U0438\U0439 \U043a\U0440\U0435\U043c\U043b\U044c",
"\U0421\U043f\U0430\U0441\U0441\U043a\U0430\U044f \U0431\U0430\U0448\U043d\U044f",
"\U0410\U0440\U0445\U0430\U043d\U0433\U0435\U043b\U044c\U0441\U043a\U0438\U0439 \U0441\U043e\U0431\U043e\U0440",
"\U0423\U0441\U043f\U0435\U043d\U0441\U043a\U0438\U0439 \U0441\U043e\U0431\U043e\U0440",
"\U0411\U043b\U0430\U0433\U043e\U0432\U0435\U0449\U0435\U043d\U0441\U043a\U0438\U0439 \U0441\U043e\U0431\U043e\U0440",
"\U041a\U043e\U043b\U043e\U043a\U043e\U043b\U044c\U043d\U044f \U0418\U0432\U0430\U043d\U0430 \U0412\U0435\U043b\U0438\U043a\U043e\U0433\U043e",
```

Im not sure that it may help, but if you ask for `NSLog` array's there it is..

Comment: You can achieve this using predicate but better approach is to keep whole entity object in array and display only names from it.

Comment: I have only array of "names" and array of all objects, what exactly should i do?

Comment: I didn't got that.Can you please show us the NSlog of both arrays.

Comment: while performing search you are storing only name property of the entity. rather than that store entire object and in table show only name property of it.

Comment: Why don't you just iterate all value to look for the item you want?

Comment: Eonil - that is what I'm asking for, i don't know how iterate to "catch" properties that correct for specific name. Pooja M. Bohora - that may help, but it seems like i need to rework all my class. Not sure there isn't better way to achieve my task.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban You will need to use predicates for that.

Comment: You don't *have* to use predicates. Look at the many `[NSArray indexOfObject...]` methods as well.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Search is based on name. So predicates will be needed.

Comment: Nope `[NSArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:]` would work as well.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Yes I thought only indexofobject method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of find all the objects with a matching name would be:

```
NSMutableArray *array = ...;    // Array of YourObject instances
NSString *wantedName = @"Germany";
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    YourObject *yourObject = (YourObject *)obj;
    return [yourObject.name isEqualToString:wantedName];
}];
```

Note: That's a case-sensitive match.  Use the following for case insensitive match:

```
return [yourObject.name caseInsensitiveCompare:wantedName] == NSOrderedSame;
```

Comment: Trojanfoe, thank you very much for your answer. But i only need one index (integer) instead of index set. I think your approach will help me (all other solutions provided here helpful as well).

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Just use `[NSArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:]` instead then.  However I would be tempted to always use the code in my answer and `NSAssert([indexSet count] == 0 || [indexSet count] == 1, @"Something bad happened");` for development sanity-check.

Comment: Thank you trojanfoe. I will definitely use it, and hope that nothing bad will ever happen to my app ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just don't take the names out of the objects. Instead, sort the objects and then get the name of each to display on the table (so you should never have just a list of names).

Technically you could run a search (iterate or predicate) on the objects to find the 'one' with the matching name, but there may be duplicates, and it's possible you may allow editing of the names later so having a copy in another list is a maintenance issue. You could keep an index, but then you're creating a container object just to hold the index when you can just use the original list of objects directly.

Comment: I think I have suggested the same :)

Comment: Absolutely; decomposing an already good model collection, just for display is unncessary.

Comment: @PoojaM.Bohora true, I didn't read the comments before answering (I'd encourage you to add an answer in future as your comment is right on the mark and just needed a little additional info to be a fine answer)

Comment: Wain that sound like a good solution (PoojaM.Bohora did suggest the same, right), but I'm not sure i understand how iterate through "names" properties while searching (using "whole" array), thats why i create filtered names array.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban keep an array, but it should be an array of the objects (sorted for whatever order you want to display in). When you need the name for a cell, the same index into the array applies, but you get an object instead of a name (`PlaceHolder *objectAtIndex = [self.arrayOfObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`). Then, the name is `objectAtIndex.name;`

Comment: Thank you Wain for your answer. it look much more convenient then creating new array of names.